# Mongodump from MongoDB 4 and Mongorestore to MongoDB 5

Tags: mongodb, version, backup, mongodump, mongorestore

After reading this in the official Mongo Documentation: https://docs.mongodb.com/database-tools/mongorestore/#restore-to-matching-server-version

I‘m having doubts on how the best practice is in the following case.

Our old Server has Mongo 4 installed and our new Server is Running Mongo 5. Both Stand-alone installations.

I can‘t install or Update Mongo on the old Server.

Is there a way on how i can transfer my databases without having Datacorruption or Problems like the official Documentation talks about?

I know i have to use the —gzip tag, but that‘s about it.

Thanks for helping.

Comment: Wast that answer helpful?

Answer (score 0):

It is a recommendation to use the same verdion

Mongo tools are now separate package and had its own version.

[restore](https://docs.mongodb.com/database-tools/mongorestore/#compatibility) is compatible with mongo 4 and 5.

[dump](https://docs.mongodb.com/database-tools/mongodump/#compatibility) also compatible with verdion 4 and 5.

But if there are some unsupported things in mongo 5 from mongo 4 which is used in your schema and queries, you would take a dump and give a try out in your prestaging environment.

And do not forget to read about the release notes.

Apart from the mentioned versions, it also says

> > While mongodump may work on earlier versions of MongoDB server, any such compatibility is not guaranteed.